# Test redux actions file properly

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

im writing a react app who has a default state management: View dispatch an action than change reducer state. I was able to test the view and the reducer but didn't find a way to test my actions file because return a dispatch function

Action File that need to be tested:

```
import {Dispatch} from 'redux'

import {AuthAction, AuthActionTypes, SetUserAction} from "../actions-types/auth-actions-types";

export const setUserAction  = (user: User) =>  {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<SetUserAction>) => {
    dispatch({
      type: AuthActionTypes.SET_USER,
      payload: user
    })
  }
```

}

reducer

```
  import {AuthAction, AuthActionTypes} from "../actions-types/auth-actions-types";
    
    export const initialAuthState = {
      auth: {},
      user: null
    };
    
    const reducer = (state = initialAuthState, action: AuthAction) =>  {
      switch(action.type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.SET_USER:
          return {
            ...state,
            user: action.payload,
          };
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
    
    export default reducer
```

reducer Test working ok.

```
    import authReducer, {initialAuthState} from "./auth-reducer";
import {AuthActionTypes} from "../actions-types/auth-actions-types";

describe('Auth Reducer', ()=>{
  test('should return user correclty ', ()=>{
    const mockPayload = {
      name: 'any_name',
      emaiL: 'any_email',
      accessToken: 'any_tokem'
    }

    const newState = authReducer(initialAuthState, {
      type: AuthActionTypes.SET_USER,
      payload: mockPayload
    })

    expect(newState.user).toEqual(mockPayload);
  })
})
```

Action File test with problems

```
 describe('AuthAction', ()=>{

      test('setUserAction', ()=>{
 const user = {
        name: 'any_user',
        email: 'any_email',
        token: 'any_token'
      }
          const result = setUserAction();
          expect(result).toEqual(user);
      })
    })
    
    Expected: {"email": "any_email", "name": "any_user", "token": "any_token"}
    Received: [Function anonymous]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Writing an action creator

Here is the official documentation that shows how to create an [action creator](https://redux.js.org/usage/reducing-boilerplate#action-creators)

I do not see the benefit for your action creator to do a dispatch, you can simply write it and use it in the following way:

```js
// action.ts
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'
import { AuthAction, AuthActionTypes, SetUserAction } from "../actions-types/auth-actions-types";

export const setUser  = (user: User) => ({
  type: AuthActionTypes.SET_USER,
  payload: user
})

// somewhere.ts
dispatch(setUser(user))
```

Now the redux team recommends using [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) and they provide a simple tool called [`createAction`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction)

And if you want to create your reducer and action creator at the same time in the easier possible way you can use [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createslice)

### How to test a reducer and an action?

To avoid an opinionated response to this answer you have two paths:

- testing reducer with your action creator
- a test for the reducer and a test for the action

#### Testing a reducer with your action creator

The reducer test should confirm that the triggered action has the expected impact.

Here is an example of using your reducer and your action creator together:

```js
describe('Auth Reducer', ()=>{
  test('should set user correctly', ()=> {
    const newState = authReducer(initialAuthState, setUser(mockPayload))

    expect(newState.user).toEqual(mockPayload);
  })
})
```

The **benefit of this is** that you just write one test and you assert that both **action creator and reducer work well together**.

#### How to test an action creator alone?

You do not need to test your action creator if you test your reducer with it.

An action is just an object with a `type` and `payload` basically, so you can test it in the following way

```
describe('AuthAction', () => {
  test('setUserAction', () => {
    const user = {
      name: 'any_user',
      email: 'any_email',
      token: 'any_token'
    }
    const result = setUser(user);
    expect(result).toEqual({ type: AuthActionTypes.SET_USER, user });
  })
})
```

Comment: I just want to piggy-back on this answer and make this very clear: Redux Toolkit is the officially recommended way of writing Redux since 2019. You should not be writing action creators by hand nowadays, and as a result you will also not have any need to test them. (in fact, modern Redux does not even have "action files".) Please read https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for adding this @phyr, you are right
Today we usually test reducer with the action creator together and we do not have to do specific tests for the action creator